# Possible to create a dual y axis chart but where the secondary y series is using a secondary x axis?

Tags: highcharts

I'm able to create in Excel a chart where...

The data is in a different date frequency based on the x axis

Two different chart types - line over bars

So for example, I can have a bar chart on the primary x-axis / y-axis that is aggregated by year.  Then another series as a line that changes on a daily basis.  What allows the line to show up as a daily time series (raw values) is the option to turn on the secondary x-axis.  With this on, the two time series can work off a different date frequency.

Is this possible in highcharts?  I've only been able to find examples of where it's possible to enable the secondary y-axis but both time series is in the same date frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The method to add a second `x` axis is exactly the same as it is to add a secondary `y` axis - you just make the changes to the `xAxis` properties instead of the `yAxis` properties, and specify the `xAxis` for you series instead of specifying the `yAxis`.

Example:

```
  xAxis: [{

  }, {
    opposite: true
  }]
```

And:

```
  series: [{
    data: [...data...]
  }, {
    xAxis: 1,
    type: 'line',
    data: [...data...]
  }]
```

Fiddle example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ko7ton0w/

Comment: Thanks!   I didn't think of adding xaxis : 1 in the series.